# How can i find the angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, displacement

[image]

Here we have a question of a 2 dimensional movement. I know that it is needed to get its second derivatives for acceleration but then what should I do?

Comment: Do you know how to use a scalar product?

Comment: Yes but I get really confused to how use it in this situation.

Comment: Find $\vec a$ and $\vec r$, and then you can get your answer.

Comment: I love the instruction “Take g=10 m/s$^2$”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your position vector is:
$$
\vec{r}(t)=\big( x(t),y(t) \big)
$$
and your acceleration vector is:
$$
\vec{a}(t) = \frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2} = \big( \ddot{x}(t), \ddot{y}(t) \big)
$$
then, the internal product is:
$$
\vec{r} \, \cdot \vec{a} = |\vec{r}| \, |\vec{a}| \,cos(\theta)
$$
but also:
$$
\vec{r} \, \cdot \vec{a} = x\ddot{x} + y\ddot{y}
$$
therefore:
$$
\theta= cos^{-1} \bigg( \dfrac{x\ddot{x} + y\ddot{y}}{|\vec{r}| \, |\vec{a}|} \bigg)
$$